# Module not found error when adding worker-loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, yarnpkg, worker-loader

I am working on my vue app and I am trying to add worker-loader. These are the stops I have followed. I added worker-loader using yarn.

```
yarn add worker-loader
```

main.js

```
import Worker from "worker-loader!./Worker.js";
```

environment.js

```
environment.loaders.append('worker-loader', {
  test: /\.worker\.js$/,
  use: [{ 
    loader: "worker-loader"
  }],
});

module.exports = environment;
```

The error I am getting is

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Worker.js' in '/Users/app/javascript/packs/home'
```

Please have me find where I am going wrong and help me setup worker-loader.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```js
import Worker from "worker-loader!./Worker.js";
```

With this [snippet from the docs](https://yarnpkg.com/package/worker-loader)

```js
import Worker from "./file.worker.js";

const worker = new Worker();

worker.postMessage({ a: 1 });
worker.onmessage = function (event) {};

worker.addEventListener("message", function (event) {});
```

if that doesn't work I have had success by changing the previous line to

```js
import Worker from 'worker-loader!./file.worker.js';
```

from this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56167322/2073738)

Comment: I tried with the above two stated options, 
for the first case I am getting the error: Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/web/FetchCompileWasmTemplatePlugin'.
for the last case I am getting error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './file.worker.js' in app/javascript/packs/home'.